# Passing a variable to another page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi fellow stackoverflow.

I'm trying to send variable from page 1 to page 2 without PHP session.

Here's my page 1 code :

```
<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
}

</script>
```

Ajax function in page 1:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location = "http://google.com";}, 3000);
```

Original code with the Ajax in page 1 :

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location = "http://google.com" + getQueryVariable("affid");}, 3000);
```

The script gets the backlink code and attached it into the affid.

So now i'm figuring out how to pass variable to page 2.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: That's not AJAX, that's a redirect. What's your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck , I would like to get a variable to page two the getquery variable.

Comment: @EdCottrell , actually the Ajax code is very long but i just took the certain function which I want to do with my Ajax is it possible to pass it together with the ajax?

Comment: Why can't you just use a form?

Comment: @Daedalus , hmmm , I'm trying not to depend on form.

Comment: @McKin You're making this needlessly complicated.

Comment: @Daedalus , cannot session it via javascript?

Comment: @McKin What you have posted so far doesn't involve AJAX at all. You need to be more clear about what you're trying to do.